# should I blame PostgreSQL -- transaction fails with DDL

Tags: spring, postgresql, transactions, ddl

some backgrounds:

I have a workflow app(java ee.) which has nodes chained to be executed.
PostgreSQL 9.1.2 is used with Spring TX management.

nodes execute in its own transaction (required, read committed).
node-1(TX1) will create a table TB_NODE_1 to pass the data to the next node -- node2.
this is done in TX1.

after TX1 commits, node2 will be triggered to be executed(in TX2).
the first thing node2 does is to read TB_NODE_1 as its input.

the problem:

It happens , mostly under heavy load(really LARGE queries hits PostgreSQL, concurrently), node2 complains : **relation TB_NODE_1 does not exist**.

some details:

1. I create TB_NODE_1 using "create table tb_node_1 as select * from table_foobar where ...".
2. TX1 is guaranteed to commit by Spring TX.
3. PostgreSQL will **not** keep table created in TX1 if TX1 rolled back.
4. TX1 is not rolled back (no exception occurs in TX1).

It seems PostgreSQL give me a fake result that TX1 is committed , but actually it does not.

Does anybody have the same problem?

Comment: `after TX1 commits`. How do you know that it committed? Do you wait for the next "prompt" or do you just fire-and-forget?

Comment: hi, [Springframework](http://www.springsource.org/) TX manager  ensures TX being committed before app code method returns.

Comment: How does it ensure the commit? Turn query logging on in PostgreSQL and check in what order your code is executed.

Comment: Painfully discovered that Postgres does not support Autonomous Transactions, although there's certainly a Spring annotation for it. Compounding the injury, certain transactions that one think might be sequential and independent can get wrapped in an outer transaction. As such, when a rollback happens, everything, not just the independent transaction, gets reverted. This can lead to problems similar to what you've described, where you're certain something committed, according to the documentation, but the reality is the underlying implementation hasn't or can't. Frank Heilken's advice is sound.